# No response from twitter api with request_token

Tags: php, curl, twitter-oauth

I have been trying to follow the steps laid out in the docs for twitter sign in here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

My Code:

```
$oauth_consumer_secret = '***';
$access_token_secret = '***';

$oauth_consumer_key = '***';
$oauth_nonce = createNonce();
$oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
$oauth_time = time();
$oauth_token = '***';
$oauth_version = '1.0';

$oauth = array(
    'oauth_callback' => '***',
    'oauth_consumer_key'=>$oauth_consumer_key,
    'oauth_nonce'=>$oauth_nonce,
    'oauth_signature_method'=>$oauth_signature_method,
    'oauth_timestamp'=>$oauth_time,
    'oauth_token'=>$oauth_token,
    'oauth_version'=>$oauth_version
);

$baseURI = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/oauth/request_token';
$baseString = buildBaseString($baseURI,$oauth);
$compositeKey = getCompositeKey($oauth_consumer_secret,null);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $compositeKey, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature; //add the signature to our oauth array

$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth));
$login = loginUser($baseURI,$header);
echo $login;

function loginUser($baseURI,$header){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseURI);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($output!=''){
        return $output;
    } else {
        return 'fail';
    };
};

function buildBaseString($baseURI,$params){
    $r = array(); // temp array
    ksort($params); // sorts params alphabetically by key
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = '$key='.rawurlencode($value);
    };
    return 'POST&'.rawurlencode($baseURI).'&'.rawurlencode(implode('&', $r)); // returns complete base string
};

// Create composite key
function getCompositeKey($consumerSecret,$requestToken){
    return rawurlencode($consumerSecret) . '&' . rawurlencode($requestToken);
};

function createNonce(){
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $string = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<32; $i++) {
            $string .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    };
    return $string;
};

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth){
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth '; //header prefix
    $values = array(); //temporary key=value array
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
    $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\""; //encode key=value string
    $r .= implode(', ', $values); //reassemble
    return $r; //return full authorization header
};
```

The Problem I am having is that I am getting no response what so ever! So the login function just keeps returning 'fail'.

When I change curlopt_ssl_verifypeer to false I get a HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized error.

Any help or clues would be appreciated.

Comment: If you aren't too worried about writing your own implementation, you might look at using a prebuilt [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL and OAuth issues are most likely separate.

As for SSL, your certificate authoririty (CA) bundle is most likely out of date. You can either tell curl to not verify the peer CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = 0 or update the CA bundle. You can download a [current CA bundle here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html). Most people (myself included) just turn off VERIFYPEER. Although this practice should be discouraged, it's a common solution.

When generating the request token, you do not need oauth_token in your oauth parameters. You are asking for a request token, you don't have one yet. Not sure if this matters, but only use `','` as the delimiter, not `', '` as in `$r .= implode(', ', $values); //reassemble`

I looked through the rest of your implementation and it looks right. Having written my own, I can appreciate the difficulty here.